# How to handle zero inflated data and incorporate random effect in beta regression?

Tags: mixed-model, biostatistics, beta-distribution, zero-inflation

My research question - how does the inbreeding level change in different age (life stages)? I have data of about 12000 observation done in different year (2007 to 2014) and 10 different islands (different islands also differ so island should be random effect).

My response variable (FROH) is continuous and lies in the closed interval [0,1]. It has excess zero and is close to zero; it is proportional data, and my predictor variable (life stage i.e. nestling, juvenile, adult) is categorical. I find my data follows the beta distribution (I see in the histogram and apply `descdist` function from the `fitdistrplus` package to find distribution ).

I find betaregression (betareg) does not work because of having 0.
One option I found is adding a small constant to remove zero. Still, I also have random factors. My data is repeated observation.  I find that beta regression does not account for random factors. In such conditions, how do we do statistical modelling??

Comment: First you say your response is continuous. Then you say it is categorical. Also, you say it follows a beta distribution but is zero inflated.

Comment: If you're working in R you can see the mixed models task view: https://cran.r-project.org/web/views/MixedModels.html . At least the `brms` and `glmmTMB` packages offer zero-inflated Beta responses with models including random effects ...

Comment: I think OP meant to say their *predictor* variable (life stage) was categorical?

Comment: yeah my predictor is categorical but response is continious..